# "Device Explorer" missing on Android Studio "Giraffe" (M1 Mac)?

Tags: android

Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
MacBook Pro 16" 2021 (Apple Silicon)
macOS X Ventura 13.4.1 (c) (22F770820d)

I recently installed (just the other day actually) Android Studio on my PC and was able to browse my AVDs filesystem using "Device Explorer" in Android Studio.

However, when trying to do the same on my Mac the "folder"-icon is greyed out in **Device Manager** and I can't find **Device Explorer** in the menubar under **Tools**.

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio's Device Manager with the Device Explorer icon greyed out]

Am I missing something?